# Pinterest type tagged buttons

Tags: tcl

I want to make some dynamic buttons with tags names on -

add_tag "name" should make a little button with
a cross at the right to remove the button - the interaction should be rather like the way tags in this posting are added

Has anybody made such a thing?

This is for TCL/TK 8.6

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
proc add_tag_close_btn {t} {
  # button inside tag widget without border with red x :
  set b ${t}.x
  button $b -text "x" -bd 0 -fg red -command [list destroy $t]
  # place it at top/right corner, 8x8 size:
  place $b -anchor ne -rely 0 -relx 1 -height 8 -width 8
}

# test:
foreach i {1 2 3 4 5} {
  set t .tag$i
  button $t -text "Tag Btn $i" -command "..."
  grid $t -column $i -row 1
  $t configure -width 10
  add_tag_close_btn $t
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My take -

```
catch {font delete MySmallFont}
font create MySmallFont {*}[font configure TkDefaultFont] -size 6

proc make_tag_window {w text {color yellow}} {
    # Pad with spaces to leave a little gap
    label $w -text "$text   " -background $color

    # Placement cosmetics easier with a smaller font and no padding
    set closew [button $w.b -text X -font MySmallFont -background $color -relief flat -pady 0 -borderwidth 0 -command [list destroy $w]]

    # Place X in top left corner. We do not use -width -height because they can truncate
    place $closew -in $w -relx 1 -anchor ne -bordermode outside
    raise $closew
    return $w
}

#demo
grid [make_tag_window .t1 "Tag A"] [make_tag_window .t2 "Tag B" red]
```